# Using ICapturegraphBuilder in DirectShow

Tags: c++, directshow

I am working on Direct Show samples, and have run into a problem. I want to multiplex video recievedfrom capture device to both preview and file, but do not know how.

The sample i use as base is playcap. In there, `ICaptureGraphBuilder2` is used; in its documentation is function `SetOutputFileName` that presumably turns on file output.

In practive, though, file appears in the file system, but is always empty and is deleted when  the application exits. I suspect wrong usage of the API on my part.

Here is the code i am using:

```
    HRESULT hr;
IBaseFilter *pSrcFilter=NULL;

// Get DirectShow interfaces
hr = GetInterfaces();
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Msg(TEXT("Failed to get video interfaces!  hr=0x%x"), hr);
    return hr;
}

// Attach the filter graph to the capture graph
hr = g_pCapture->SetFiltergraph(g_pGraph);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Msg(TEXT("Failed to set capture filter graph!  hr=0x%x"), hr);
    return hr;
}

// Use the system device enumerator and class enumerator to find
// a video capture/preview device, such as a desktop USB video camera.
hr = FindCaptureDevice(&pSrcFilter);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    // Don't display a message because FindCaptureDevice will handle it
    return hr;
}

// Add Capture filter to our graph.
hr = g_pGraph->AddFilter(pSrcFilter, L"Video Capture");
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Msg(TEXT("Couldn't add the capture filter to the graph!  hr=0x%x\r\n\r\n") 
        TEXT("If you have a working video capture device, please make sure\r\n")
        TEXT("that it is connected and is not being used by another application.\r\n\r\n")
        TEXT("The sample will now close."), hr);
    pSrcFilter->Release();
    return hr;
}
IBaseFilter * pBaseFilter;
IFileSinkFilter  *pfSink;
// Attach the file writerto the capture graph
hr = g_pCapture->SetOutputFileName (&MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,L"output.avi",&pBaseFilter,&pfSink);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Msg(TEXT("Failed to set capture filter graph!  hr=0x%x"), hr);
    return hr;
}
// Render the preview pin on the video capture filter
// Use this instead of g_pGraph->RenderFile
hr = g_pCapture->RenderStream (&PIN_CATEGORY_PREVIEW, &MEDIATYPE_Video,
                               pSrcFilter, NULL, NULL);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Msg(TEXT("Couldn't render the video capture stream.  hr=0x%x\r\n")
        TEXT("The capture device may already be in use by another application.\r\n\r\n")
        TEXT("The sample will now close."), hr);
    pSrcFilter->Release();
    return hr;
}
// Now that the filter has been added to the graph and we have
// rendered its stream, we can release this reference to the filter.
pSrcFilter->Release();

// Set video window style and position
hr = SetupVideoWindow();
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Msg(TEXT("Couldn't initialize video window!  hr=0x%x"), hr);
    return hr;
}

// Add our graph to the running object table, which will allow
// the GraphEdit application to "spy" on our graph
hr = AddGraphToRot(g_pGraph, &g_dwGraphRegister);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Msg(TEXT("Failed to register filter graph with ROT!  hr=0x%x"), hr);
    g_dwGraphRegister = 0;
}
// Start previewing video data
hr = g_pMC->Run();
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Msg(TEXT("Couldn't run the graph!  hr=0x%x"), hr);
    return hr;
}

// Remember current state
g_psCurrent = Running;

return S_OK;
```

How should i achieve functionality i want?

Answer (score 0):

In above code you are passing NULL to RenderStream as last parameter.

At [RenderStream msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa930715.aspx)

it is stated:

If the pSink parameter is NULL, the method tries to use a default renderer. For video it uses the Video Renderer, and for audio it uses the Audio Renderer (WaveOut) Filter.

On the same above link, please have a look at the code snippet:

```
pBuilder->SetOutputFileName(&MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi, L"C:\\Example.avi",
    &ppf, &pSink);
pBuilder->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, &MEDIATYPE_Video,
    pCaptureFilter, NULL, ppf);
```

You might want to look at [AmCap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) also.